# Nested eager loading with attribute accessors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, lazy-loading, rails-models

I have my models setup like this:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :manufacturers
end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country
   has_many :cars
end

class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :manufactuer
   has_many :comfort_levels

   attr_accessor :attr_accessor_1, :attr_accessor_2
end

class ComfortLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car
end
```

This is how I am eager loading `manufacturers` with `cars` (including car's attr accessors) for a country:

```
data = current_country.manufacturers.to_json :include => {:cars => {:methods => [:attr_accessor_1, :attr_accessor_1]}}
```

What will be the syntax to also eager load the `comfort levels` for `cars` in the above call?

I have tried various things, but no luck so far.

Would greatly appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to eager load everything, using:

```
data = current_country.manufacturers.to_json :include => [{:cars => {:methods => [:attr_accessor_1, :attr_accessor_1]}}, :comfort_levels]
```

The above call did not nest `comfort level` records inside `car` records, however, the following did:

```
data = current_country.manufacturers.to_json :include => {:cars => {:methods => [:attr_accessor_1, :attr_accessor_1, :comfort_levels]}}
```

This [link](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/beauty-nested-include-option) helped me clear some concepts around the syntax for eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`data = current_country.manufacturers.to_json :include => {:cars => {:methods => [:attr_accessor_1, :attr_accessor_1], :comfort_levels => {}}}`

Comment: Thanks varatis, but that throws syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC.

Comment: This time it didn't throw any syntax errors, but seems like it still didn't load any attributes from `comfort levels`

Comment: And sorry, I should have used the term 'eager loading'. I have updated the question.